# Quasar Dialog with CodeMirror

Tags: vue.js, codemirror, quasar

I have code mirror working in a dialog but the line numbers and gutter spacing seems to be over the first 5 characters of the text.

[image]

as soon as you start typing the number jump to where they should be but the gutter part still stays and overlaps the content as you type

[image]

This only happens on dialogs, when i add the code mirror to normal page (out side of a dialog) it works 100%.

And reason why this is happening. I have added ‘refresh: true’ to the option and still does not help.

Thanks

Comment: try using `autoRefresh: true`, this refreshes the codemirror every time a change is made, rather that refreshing on initialization.

Comment: Hi @Souleste it still has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was searching everywhere and could not find any answer.

Ended up using this and works perfectly.

https://github.com/run-ze/vue-ace

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS fix CodeMirror on Quasar Dialog

```html
<style >
    .CodeMirror-lines { 
        padding-left: 25px 
    }
</style>
```